# openproject configure throws "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"?

Tags: openproject

Installed openproject according to the CentOS 7 docs (https://www.openproject.org/download-and-installation/#installation) and after running `sudo openproject configure`, getting the error output as shown:

```sh
➜  ~ sudo openproject configure 
Launching installer for openproject...
Selected addons: legacy-installer mysql apache2 repositories smtp memcached openproject
[legacy-installer] ./bin/configure
[mysql] ./bin/configure
DONE
[apache2] ./bin/configure
DONE
[repositories] ./bin/configure
DONE
[smtp] ./bin/configure
DONE
[memcached] ./bin/configure
DONE
[openproject] ./bin/configure
[legacy-installer] ./bin/preinstall
[mysql] ./bin/preinstall
[apache2] ./bin/preinstall
Note: Forwarding request to 'systemctl enable httpd.service'.
[repositories] ./bin/preinstall
[smtp] ./bin/preinstall
[memcached] ./bin/preinstall
No memcached server to install. Skipping.
[openproject] ./bin/preinstall
[legacy-installer] ./bin/postinstall
[mysql] ./bin/postinstall
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Never used MariaDB before, but from some basic checking (installed following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password)

```sql
➜  ~ mysqladmin -u root -p version
Enter password: 
mysqladmin  Ver 9.0 Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB, for Linux on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Server version      5.5.60-MariaDB
Protocol version    10
Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket     /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:         21 min 38 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 16  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 7  Flush tables: 2  Open tables: 25  Queries per second avg: 0.012
```

(where the passsword is just blank) the DB appears to be working and accessible. Removing and re-installing the mariadb-server package does not appear to change the behavior either. Never used openproject or mysql / mariadb before, so any advice on what could be happening here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you choose `Install and configure MySQL server locally` during the configuration step?

[image]

If so, the package should automatically configure a random MySQL root password that is stored under the key `mysql/root_password` at `/etc/openproject/installer.dat`. If you can still access the database with an empty password, the setup failed to set a password correctly. [It appears to take input from urandom](https://github.com/pkgr/installer/blob/master/wizard#L80).

What you could try is running the following command while hitting enter in the MySQL password prompt:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p password "<Create and insert a random password here>"
```

And then replacing the value at `mysql/root_password` at `/etc/openproject/installer.dat`.

Comment: is there no way to set the mysql password into a file used by `openproject configure`???? I cannot find any `root_password` file into my openproject installation

Comment: The root_password is not a separate file, but a string variable in the file /etc/openproject/installer.dat , but only if you chose to autoinstall MySQL from the wizard

Comment: where does `openproject configure` take its mysql password from?